# Не получается установить libgdiplus через докер

Tags: c#, .net, docker

На локальном пк все работает(Виндоус). Есть такой докерфайл. Насколько я понимаю для работы на линукс нужна libgdiplus-библиотека.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./HelloBackend .
RUN dotnet restore
WORKDIR /app/hello
RUN dotnet publish -c Release

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/hello/bin/Release/net5.0 ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "hello.dll"]
```

Как ее установить через докерфайл?

Comment: [Оно](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/618#issuecomment-405979425)?

Comment: @aepot оно но я с докером не работал, и не много не понимаю в какой строке оно должно быть

Comment: Сразу после from … as runtime